# Rewriting stored procedure as a transaction

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a stored procedure in the form of:

```
CREATE FUNCTION schema.myfunction(id uuid)
RETURNS TABLE (report jsonb) AS $$
  BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY WITH rows AS (
    SELECT
      jsonb_build_object(
      'rowNumber', ROW_NUMBER(),
      'id', t.id
    ) AS row
  FROM schema.table t
  WHERE t.id = id
  )
  SELECT
    COALESCE(jsonb_agg(r.row), '[]') AS report
  FROM rows r;
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT STABLE SECURITY DEFINER;

  GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION schema.myfunction(    
        uuid
  ) TO schema_user;
```

How can I get the same result but running this function as a transaction? Without creating the function itself. Something in the form of:

```
db.transaction(async (trx) => {
      const {
        rows: [result],
      } = await trx.raw(
        '<supposed code here, maybe>;',
        [id]
      );

      res.status(200).json(result);
}
```

Is it possible?

I tried with DO block but I can't return anything from it. Any guidance on the right direction would help tremendously.

Comment: A function is always run inside the transaction of the caller. So there is no need to move the code out of your function in order to be able to make it as part of a transaction. But in the end, you should be able to run the actual query of your function (`with rows as (...) select ... from rows`) as a regular SQL query in your programming language

Comment: Thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name, it worked as expected. Keep on neighing, you the mvp.